# Filter by two fields in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code that filters through a field and marks the words that relate to the input search. I need this filtered me not only by the title, but also by the name. How can I modify the code so that when I write, I filter both title and name?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search.title"
   ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search.title">
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sgo3wxwc/

Comment: I can't find `name` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I still can't find `name`..

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari look http://jsfiddle.net/sgo3wxwc/

Answer (score 0):

you can send two or more options to filter by gathering them in object:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{title:search.title,name:search.name}"
   ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search.title">
</li>
```

it's recommended to use filters in controller to avoid $digest cycle on them

Comment: How do I display both elements on the same line?

Comment: you can bind like this <div>{{item.title - item.name}}</div>

Comment: I modify the link. http://jsfiddle.net/sgo3wxwc/ my problem continues..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.title">
  <ul>
      <!-- with filter -->
       <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{title:search.title,name:search.name}"
   ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search.title">
         {{item}}
      </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

script code is here:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
            { title: "Bad",name:'bill' },
            { title: "Good",name:'Goe' },
            { title: "Great",name:'Brad' },
            { title: "Cool",name:'yan' },
            { title: "Excellent",name:'mikle' },
            { title: "Awesome",name:'mosa' },
            { title: "Horrible",name:'morteza' },
          ]

}).filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
  })
```

Comment: It would be perfect, but I need the filter to work with names, too.